# How to find a link in HTML under a certain header AND parse it

Tags: c#, html, linq, html-agility-pack

I am currently attempting to parse a link from an HTML doc based off the header above it, but no matter what I try, the program is unable to find it. 
Here is the method I have that isn't working:

```
    public string findMajorURL(string collegeURL, string major)
    {
        HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
        doc.LoadHtml(collegeURL);
        var root = doc.DocumentNode;
        var htmlNodes = root.Descendants();
        //Find html node containing the major heading
        foreach(HtmlNode node in htmlNodes)
        {
            if (node.InnerText == major)
            {
                HtmlNode target = node.NextSibling;
                List<string> links = target.Descendants("a").Select(a => a.Attributes["href"].Value).ToList();
                return links.First()+ "__IT WORKED__";
            }
        }
        return "Major not found";
    }
```

This is what the HTML looks like that I am attempting to parse:

```
    <div style="padding-left: 20px">
       <h3 id="ent1629">Biological Sciences </h3>
       <a href="preview_entity.php?catoid=5&ent_oid=1629&returnto=818">Go to information for this department.</a>
       <br>
       <p>...</p>
       <div id="data_c_1629" style="display: none">...</div>
       <!--script language="javascript">hideshow(data_c_1630)</script-->
```

The major the user inputs is supposed to match the heading, Biological Sciences. Based off of the header, I want to get the link **under** it, which in this case is **preview_entity.php?catoid=5&ent_oid=1629&returnto=818**

WARNING: I cannot use XPath withthe version of Visual Studio that I have, so I'm assuming using LINQ somehow would be the best way to go, but again I'm not sure.

**EDIT** It turns out that the Inner Text is not matching the major, however, I don't see how that's possible, as I took it directly from the html code. Any ideas as to what's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

According to the HTML snippet posted, `node` inside your `if` block references `<h3>` element and `target` references next sibling of `<h3>` which is `<a>`. That said, you don't need to do `target.Descendants("a")`. Just get `href` attribute from `target` directly :

```
if (node.InnerText == major)
{
    HtmlNode target = node.NextSibling;
    return target.GetAttributeValue("href", "")+ "__IT WORKED__";
}
```

Comment: I tried this, but apparently it's not even entering the if statement :/  I don't understand why the inner text isn't matching up, because I even took the inner text directly from the html doc, but it still isn't matching up.